# Make Flutter GetIt returns objects dynamically in runtime

Tags: flutter, dependency-injection

I am using [GetIt](https://pub.dev/packages/get_it) library in order to provide DI in my application.

I just reached point where I want to allow user to choose between **LocalDataSource** or **NetworkDataSource**, where these two classes are subclasses of an abstract class **DataSource**. Also, I created an **enum** called **DataSourceType**, which contains two values `{local, network}`. Along with that, there is a **static** field of **DataSourceType** in **main** class of the app, which should serve as flag for **DataSource** type.
So, I created screen with two radio buttons and user can select DataSource types, and that will set static value the field in **main** class.

**The problem:**
I don't know how to register and return subclasses of the **DataSource** class using GetIt and dynamically(in runtime) return one or another subclass, depending on DataSoruceType flag.
So, if user changes the source getit will return appropriate implementation in runtime.

Example code is here:

```
class DataSource {
  static DataSourceType dataSource = DataSourceType.local;
        ...
 }

class NetworkDataSource implements DataSource {
        ...
}

class LocalDataSource implements DataSource {
        ...
}

enum DataSourceType {local, network}
```

Can somebody help me to solve this problem?
I would appreciate any help.